# At the opening of 'The Expanse,' are Belters nominally UN/MCR citizens?

Tags: the-expanse-2015, the-expanse-novels

In either the books or the show, are Belters considered legally to be citizens of the UN or the Martian Congressional Republic? They later become their own nation, but it seems unlikely the UN or the MCR wouldn't try to claim the Belters as citizens, if only because they claim the stations themselves. They also make constant references to "Earth/Mars corps," who own the stations.

Comment: I don't recall a reference. I would assume UN since everyone came from there, then later Mars declared independence. Unless belters declared allegiance to Mars then, which I assume they wouldn't, there wouldn't be much sense in Mars claiming them. Just a guess though. 